# Does a banner at the top of your website, which only shows when Javascript isn't running, hurt your SEO?

Tags: seo

I'm working on a web-app which has a nice, AngularJS based, front-end for when javascript is enabled and then falls back to a completely Javascript free, 100% server rendered version for when it isn't, with an identical URL schema.

One of the things I do is have a banner at the top of the page stating:

> *Website Name Here* works best on a modern browser with Javascript enabled

I then use Angular's one-time binding feature to hide it. ie, once AngularJS, kicks in, the banner goes away.

I don't want to use the *noscript* tag, because I am also delivering a mostly JS free version of the site to bots/web crawlers and users on older browsers (based on user agent, I sometimes don't render the scripts to load the AngularJS and related javascript), so this notification will be missed if soembody visits on IE8, for example, if the notification is in a *noscript* tag.

Will this hurt my SEO? And could this warning potentially show up in Google/Bing/etc search results for items my site may rank otherwise highly on?

Or is this a common practice, and will any decent web crawler take this kind of notification into account?

Thanks

Comment: This isn't going to affect SEO at all. I wouldn't worry about it for another second.

Comment: @JohnConde good to know, care to expand that into an answer? Very interesting

Comment: It's common to do this with JavaScript heavy sites.  It's so insignificant in terms of content, and is clearly not malicious. It's really no different then, let's say, using display:none for a fly out menu. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: It does indeed, thanks! Again, if that was an answer I would give you a green tick :)

Comment: I'm going to do that so this question doesn't linger in limbo.

Comment: This very site does the same thing... "Webmasters Stack Exchange works best with JavaScript enabled" - although this bit of text appears at the very end of the source code and is only displayed at the top with CSS.

Comment: @w3d Do you have any more info into how SE handles this without JS? Would be interesting reading

Comment: As a side note. I think that having this display on non JS browsers should be implemented by search engines to boost SEO in some way in relationship to a set number of bytes that contain JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's common to do this with JavaScript heavy sites. It's so insignificant in terms of content, and is clearly not malicious. It's really no different then, let's say, using display:none for a fly out menu.